# How to range format with nvim 0.9.0?

Tags: neovim, formatting, lsp, range

I don't set a mapping to format code because it is not something I do all the time. So previously, I used to have a command to format or range format as follows:

```
" format code
command! -range Format if <range> | exec 'lua vim.lsp.buf.range_formatting({ timeout_ms = 2000 })' | else | exec 'lua vim.lsp.buf.format({ timeout_ms = 2000 })' | endif
```

But Nvim now gives me this message:

> ```
> vim.lsp.buf.range_formatting is deprecated, use vim.lsp.formatexpr or vim.lsp.buf.format > instead. See :h deprecated
> This function will be removed in Nvim version 0.9.0
> stack traceback:
>         /usr/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/lsp/buf.lua:407: in function 'range_formatting'
>         [string ":lua"]:1: in main chunk
> ```

How can I set a command (not a key mapping) to format the selected text, when there is any, or the entire buffer if not?

Comment: I see the docs have a range option for `vim.lsp.buf.format` but I couldn't make it work. Also, all examples I could find were for key mappings, not for a command.

Comment: Is the solution working? How can we help you further?

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
command! -range Format if <range> | exec 'lua vim.lsp.buf.format({timeout_ms = 2000, range={["start"]={row=<line1>,col=0},["end"]={row=<line2>,col=0}}})' | else | exec 'lua vim.lsp.buf.format({ timeout_ms = 2000 })' | endif
```

Comment: I'm assuming `execute` is because `lua` eats the `|`?

Comment: To highlight the changes proposed I kept as much as I could the proposed solution. I didn't test without the `execute` but you are right it could be that the `lua` eats the `|`.

Comment: I'm getting an error: `attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value`. I'll look deeper later to find what is happening. Thanks for now.

Comment: Could you tell us which language and which lsp server you are using for that language?

Comment: That errors was on Javascript files. I tried in Ruby and it showed "Format request failed, no matching language servers.", which is weird, because I have language servers and it works with the full buffer format. :/

Answer (score -1):

If you have lsp connected to your current buffer, then you can use a keybinding like this:

```lua
vim.keymap.set("v", "<leader>F", vim.lsp.buf.format, { noremap = true, silent = true })
```

Then you can visually select a portion of your code, and then hit <leader>F to format only that part.

Comment: The question is about creating a command, not a mapping.